# show a form at its current state instead of new form()

Tags: c#, winforms

I have created a C# application.

Here I have two forms, *form1* and *form2*.

*form2* is called from *form1*.

Later *form2* is made hidden.

Now I want to show *form2* from *form1*.

Please give me some idea.

Comment: what does 'current state' mean ?

Comment: Not too much informative to provide an answer!

Comment: @SazzadurRahaman i got the answer, thanks fr ur comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to keep reference to `Form2` object, and when you want it to be visible, just call `frm2.Show()` - don't construct the new `Form2` object with `new Form2()` - use the existing one.

```
// You need to contruct Form2 before calling Show().
Form2 frm2 = new Form2();


// Some handler somewhere
void btnShowForm2_Click(..., ...)
{
    frm2.Show();
}
```

Edit: As Micah pointed out, you will want to hide Form2 instead of closing it:

```
private void Form2_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
  this.Hide();
  e.Cancel = true; // this cancels the close event.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You will want to use form.hide() when hiding form2 instead of form.close

keep a reference to form2 and call form.show when you want to show it again

Comment: yes i am using form.hide(),but how to make it visible from form1.

Comment: I think Burgos might have your answer

Answer (score 1):

take form2 instance variable at class level

example

```
Public Class Form1
{
Form frm2;

//Show form here
protected void Button1_Clik
{
frm2=new Form2();
frm2.Show();
}

//Even the form is hidden, you may show the same instance /same state of form again 
protected void Button2_Click()
{
frm2.Show();
}


}
```